# Execute a function when admin changes the user role

Tags: users, hooks, user-roles

How can I execute a function, when admin changes the user role of a user?

I have two user roles: one is *agent* and the other one is *client* .

My need is that when admin changes the user role of *client* to *agent*, I need to execute a specific function.

In this function I need to get the all content and meta fields of user by getting the *user id*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`set_user_role`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L883) hook, that will only fire when the user role changes:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ) 
{
    // Your code ...

}, 10, 3 );
```

If you want to restrict this to a profile update, you can use:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id ) 
{
    add_action( 'profile_update', function( $user_id )
    {
        // Your code here ...            
    } );

} );
```

Comment: could you please explain what is 10, 3 in this?

Comment: yes sure, `10` is the *priority* and `3` is the number of *input arguments*. If we use `10, 2`, then we don't get access to `$old_roles`. The default priority is `10` and the defulat # input arguments is `1`. @ronr