# Change the second role depending on the first

Tags: functions, user-roles

Hi Guys i found this code snippet on here:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ) 
{
   // Your code ...

}, 10, 3 );
```

Source: [Execute a function when admin changes the user role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194324/execute-a-function-when-admin-changes-the-user-role)

And wanted to modify it it so that it could set the user roles in the following way:

1 user has roles "level0" and "customer" -> roles "level1" and "vendor"

2 user has roles "level1" and "vendor" -> roles "level0" and "customer"

In case the admin is changing the role "level0" to "level1" the code should update the second role from "customer" to "vendor" and vice versa.

i tried the following code but it is not working:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'rb_update_user_role',10,3);
function rb_update_user_role(){

   $user_id = get_current_user_id();
   $user = new WP_User ($user_id);

   if (current_user_is('s2member_level0') && current_user_is('vendor')){

      $user->remove_role('vendor');
      $user->add_role('customer');
   }
   if(current_user_is('s2member_level1') && current_user_is ('customer')){

      $user->remove_role('customer');
      $user->add_role('vendor');
   }
}
```

Has anyone suggestions or code snippets that could help me figure this out? Or do i need another approch on this?

EDIT:

I add the second role like this when the user is activated

```
add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'add_secondary_role_new', 10, 1 );


function add_secondary_role_new( $user_id ) {
   global $members_template;

   $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

   if (user_can($members_template->member->id,'s2member_level1')){
       $user->add_role('vendor');
   }
   else{
       $user->add_role('customer');
   }
```

}

Comment: @birgire is it possible that you have a suggestion since it was your answer on the post i referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Here it is:

```
//Update Roles automatically when Membership Level changes
function rb_update_user_role( $user_id) {
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user_meta=get_userdata($user_id);
    $all_role = $user_meta->roles;

    foreach ($all_role as $role_value){
        if ($role_value === 'vendor'){
           $user->remove_role( 'vendor' );
        }
        if ($role_value === 'customer'){
           $user->remove_role( 'customer' );
        }
        if ($role_value === 's2member_level1'){
           $user->remove_role( 's2member_level1' );
           $role = 's2member_level1';
        }
        if ($role_value === 'subscriber'){
           $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
           $role = 'subscriber';
        }
    }
    if ( $role === 'subscriber' ) {
       unset($new_role);
       $new_role = array($role => 0 ,'customer' => 1) ;
       update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_capabilities', $new_role);
    } 

    if ($role === 's2member_level1'){
       unset($new_role);
       $new_role = array($role => 0,'vendor' => 1) ;
       update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_capabilities', $new_role);
    } 
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'rb_update_user_role', 99, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are operating on the current (logged in) user - you need to accept parameters in your callback so that you can operate on the user *whose role is being set*:

```
rb_update_user_role( $user_id, $role ) {
    // error_log( "Setting user $user_id to role $role" );

    if ( $role !== 's2member_level0' && $role !== 's2member_level1' )
        return;

    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    if ( $role === 's2member_level0' ) {
        $user->remove_role( 'vendor' );
        $user->add_role( 'customer' );
    } else {
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' );
        $user->add_role( 'vendor' );
    }
}

add_action( 'set_user_role', 'rb_update_user_role', 10, 2 );
```

Note you do not need to remove any roles - `WP_User::set_role` explicitly removes all other roles before it fires the action.

Comment: that worked but now i got for instance an user with level1, customer and vendor but it should only be level1&vendor. so i kind of need to remove the role don't i? @TheDeadMedic

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. I've removed it anyway.

Comment: hm tried it and it still shows me all 3 roles like "level1,vendor,customer" that's strange isn't it?

Comment: Can you confirm that the action is definitely firing? Try [enabling debug logging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG), then add my debugging code without the comments (see revision), then check your `wp-content/debug.log` file after running a test.

Comment: [11-Jan-2017 12:53:08 UTC] Setting user 105 to role s2member_level1
that is what the debug log says

Comment: Okay well that's good - except now I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51596/discussion-between-bexx-and-thedeadmedic).